# Need to call angular http service from inside loop and wait for the value of the service to return before executing code below call

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Have a scenario where we have a loop and inside the loop we need to call a `http` service to get information about each item in the loop.
  Then based on the result of the service call we need to evaluate and do other work then continue on with each element in the loop. 
 I understand this will not work as coded due to the sync nature of the service call and that the service call itself is a promise.
  Just looking at the best angular way to accomplish this.  In the past I've used **`$q.all`** but I'd have to make multiple loops it seems to accomplish using **`$q.all`**.

```
     _($scope.searchResult)
        .each(function (results) {
          var specialInfo = myService.getInfo(results); // http service call
          if(specialInfo.length > 0){
            // Do something
          }
          else
          {
           // Do something else
          }
        });
```

Please note to anyone responding I need the service to return before moving on as I will be showing a modal if conditions are met. The code above is pseudocode, I know the .Then is missing on the getInfo but you get the point. Each of the loops could potentially require user input to move on before reviewing the next item in the loop.

Comment: don't put addendums in comments...update the question itself

Comment: Not to mention you can halt this loop for user input. Doesn't make sense

Comment: Not sure what you mean? This will do some logic and open a modal if criteria is met, not sure what doesn't make sense.

Comment: A loop occurs within milliseconds. You can't set it up to wait for user then continue along. Need to keep track some other way and make new request each time. Not really enough known about what you are doing

Comment: The goal is to stop the processing so I can make a decision to show a prompt dialog or some type of modal, that is possible as long as all async loading is done before hand or with the recursive way like doogle suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your code so there is no loop, but recursive async calls:

```
var currentIndex = 0;
function processNext() {
    if (currentIndex >= $scope.searchResult.length) {
        return;
    }

    var next = $scope.searchResult[currentIndex++];
    myService.getInfo(next).then(function (response) {
        var specialInfo = response.data;
        if (specialInfo.length > 0) {
            // something
        } else {
            // something else
        }

        processNext();
    });
}

processNext();
```

Alternatively, you could fetch all promises first and then process them one at a time. Keep in mind that this method *wouldn't* be advised if doing async processing on the responses (like waiting for input from a modal or executing subsequent requests):

```
var promises = $scope.searchResult.map(function (result) {
    return myService.getInfo(result);
});

$q.all(promises).then(function (responses) {
    responses.each(function (response) {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the result of a promise, you use `then()`:

```
_($scope.searchResult)
    .each(function (results) {
      myService.getInfo(results).then(function(response) {
          var specialInfo = response.data;
          if(specialInfo.length > 0) {
              // Do something
          }
          else {
              // Do something else
          }
       });
    });
```

Comment: Yes, understand then but my issue is I need the service to return when it has the data back each time AND not continue on to loop until it has the data.  Part of the code that will do something is to show a modal popup that the user is going to interact with so each loop could require the user to answer questions on a modal before moving on to the next item in the loop.

Comment: That isn't possible. You can't make an asynchronous call synchronous. The service can't return data. All it can return is a promise. Your service could return a promise for the first element, the caller would register a then callback to show a modal. When the modal service is resolved, you would call the service again with the next element, which would return another promise, etc. etc.

Comment: I understand it isn't possible as it is asynchronous, that is why I posted for alternatives.