# Jhipster: how to save multiple records in one entity

Tags: jhipster

I need to save multiple records in loop. In dialog.js i m getting my correct object which i m sending to service js to save. calling service js in loop only. while i m running this service js save function is called after dialog js loop. how is this happening? How can i save data in loop?

Dialog-controller.js

```
function save () {
     vm.isSaving = true;

     for(var i in resourceData)
     {

         vm.timesheet.sunday=resourceData[i].sunday;
         vm.timesheet.monday=resourceData[i].monday;
         vm.timesheet.tuesday=resourceData[i].tuesday;
         vm.timesheet.wednesday=resourceData[i].wednesday;
         vm.timesheet.thursday=resourceData[i].thursday;
         vm.timesheet.friday=resourceData[i].friday;
         vm.timesheet.saturday=resourceData[i].saturday;
         vm.timesheet.resource=resourceData[i].saturday;
         vm.timesheet.resource=resourceData[i];

        Timesheet.save(vm.timesheet,onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);

 }
```

this is my timesheet.service.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('timesheetApp')
        .factory('Timesheet', Timesheet);

    Timesheet.$inject = ['$resource', 'DateUtils'];

    function Timesheet ($resource, DateUtils) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/timesheets/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'save': {
                method: 'POST',
                isArray: false,
                transformRequest: function (data) {
                    alert("123");
                    var copy = angular.copy(data);
                    return angular.toJson(copy);
                }
            }
        });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't send an array of Timesheet objects in one single POST request?

Comment: Yes i have some common fields which needs to be add in all objects. Also i am using jhipster which created all these files and functions for single records. I am customizing it for multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write a recursive function, depending upon the promise returned.

```
Timesheet.save(vm.timesheet,onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
```

This returns a promise which calls you onSaveSuccess method.

in the function

```
function onSaveSuccess(){
// Need some recursive logic
}
```

Or try to implement this answer.

[Need to call angular http service from inside loop and wait for the value of the service to return before executing code below call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33354836/need-to-call-angular-http-service-from-inside-loop-and-wait-for-the-value-of-the)

Comment: thanks sumit for your comment. Added service.js also which this function is calling. I m new with angular.js can u plz suggest how to implement your suggested changes.